# Apollo query runs on page refresh but not with react router navigation?

Tags: react-router, apollo-client, graphcool

Im using React, Apollo and Graphcool. I have an account page where I need to query the logged in users details:

```
const loggedInUser = gql`
    query {
        loggedInUser {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

Logging in is done on a separate page. If the user then navigates or is automatically redirected (both with React Router) to the account page then the query comes back as null. If I give the page a hard refresh then the logged in users ID comes back from the query successfully.

Im not sure why this is happening. I don't think it could be a race condition as you can navigate to the account page after 10 seconds and it still wont return the user id unless you refresh.

Do I need to user resetStore? This could be expensive for me as a lot of data which wont have changed will need to be fetched again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to refetch the query after the user logged in as Apollo had cached the previous result of null. I added this to the login function and it now works.

```
// I added this: 
await this.props.loggedInUser.refetch();

// redirect user 
this.setState({
    redirect: true,
});
```